# Definition of saturation of multiplicative set in Bosch

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $A$. In Bosch's Algebraic Geometry book, he defines the *saturation* of $S$ to be the set $S'$ of "all elements in $A$ that are divided by an element of $S$". After defining this, he gives a problem that asks to show that $S'$ coincides with the multiplicative set $S(f):=\{g\in A\mid D(f)\subset D(g)\}$ where the containment is of distinguished open sets.

But should the definition actually be that $S'$ consists of all elements of of $A$ that *divide* an element of $S$ (instead of *are divided by*)? This would make more sense considering the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you say is correct. Here's why what Bosch has written is wrong: if $1\in S$, then $S'=A$, which is clearly not what should happen. Here's why what you've written is correct: if $a\in A$ is such that there exists $b\in A$ so that $ab\in S$, then $\frac{b}{ab}$ is an inverse for $a$ after localizing at $S$, so $a$ should be in the saturation of $S$.